# Is Etc/Unknown a valid timezone?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm getting my website visitor's timezones usings `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, but this is often returning the timezone Etc/Unknown.

Is this a valid timezone? Do you have any further information about this timezone?

Thanks

Comment: It stems from [`UCAL_UNKNOWN_ZONE_ID`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/ucal_8h.html#a0682edd5dfe37d2abe4bb9fb5a9733d9) in ICU.

Answer (score 3):

Etc/Unknown timezone states that timzone information cannot be determined based on user's preferences. To overcome this, you can use a default timezone, or allow user's to manually select it. You cannot rely on this method alone. You can use alternative methods like IP Geolocation.